# GUI freeze during "while loop" in C++

Tags: loops, c++-cli, freeze

I am a student who just started to learn C++. I learned Java before, but I feel there are (big?) differences between them.

It seems to be a very simple problem but my native language is not English, so I'm confused when I google it, and I have searched here for many days.

I would like to run the loop when I click START button until I click STOP, but the form freezes when I click start. I googled about it and I guess my code has an "infinite loop" problem. However, I cannot think of another way to do this...

---

Here is the code:

MyForm.h

## [image: Screenshot of the form]

```
private: System::Void Start_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        WLOOP(1);
}
private: System::Void Stop_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        WLOOP(0);
}
```

---

MyForm.cpp

```
void WLOOP(int check) {
    while (check==1){ 
            bla bla bla
            sleep(500);
    } 
}
```

---

I don't really know all the rules here, please tell me if I did something wrong. I would do better next time. Thank you very much.

Comment: You would have the same problem in Java. It seems you haven't grasped the basics of functions - you can't "re-call" a function with a different parameter in order to modify it.

Comment: It's 'cause everything is running on a single thread. GUI redrawing happens on the same thread as your program/loop, so until your loop ends, GUI redrawing will not take place, giving you that "not responding"/"freezing" behavior

Comment: thank you all for the help

@molbdnilo I edited like this but it seems same code :[http://puu.sh/o4Lat/5bed481cb3.txt](http://puu.sh/o4Lat/5bed481cb3.txt)

Comment: @AlexYan I see. "It run line by line with single thread, we can do nothing if the loop doesn't end" but could I change "int check" when the loop running? two thread? thank you

Comment: You could change `check` within the loop if you make it a reference: `int &check`. Not sure if that'll fix your problem though. I have no idea how to go about making it multithreaded. I'm a student myself as well, and I've only used threads on very rare occasions, and only on Java/Android where there are specific tools for this purpose